# PPS NAL units in mp4 file samples

Tags: video, h.264

I’m faced with strange case then mp4 file has both acvC atoms with SPS and PPS and in additional I see PPS in sample itself. so If I add SPS then PPS to IDR the next NAL will be PPS from sample itself. The problem in this case iphone doesn’t play such stream. I checked with Wowza server and in case if 7 or 8 NAL is in sample they will not include PPS or SPS from avcC atom. ffmpeg from another hand don't care about PPS in sample and insert both PPS from acvC atom and keep sample's PPS as well is there any algorithm described how to handle this ?

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your issue. Your question has no context. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not very clear.

Comment: Parameter sets are allowed to be both "in band" and "out of band", as NAL units they are interleaved with other. If your PS does not change for the whole stream, you can put it out of band as a stream descriptor and to not mess with frames. Otherwise if PS changes, there is no other way but to place it in band. You supposedly have compatibility issues because you put them in band for whatever reason. If it's just a duplicate - you can drop it. Maybe you are putting is without frame NALU, just PS, or you are attaching PS to frames other than I?

Comment: Roman, thanks for your answer. I add PS to I-frames only. actually my trasmuxer get sample of video stream and if it's I-frame I add delimiter NAL, PPS and SPS automatically now without analysing sample's NALs. I agree I can check NALs before adding SPS or PPS and add them only in case we don't have such NALs in sample itself. MPEG2TS force to add delimiter,SPS and PPS before every I-frame. But  where can I find recommended way in standard. What should I do if SPS NAL is after several actual video slices ? should I add default SPS NAL(from acvC) before slices ?

Comment: Is there any thoughts about the subject? The question is simple-how to add default(located in avcC atom) NALs in case if we have such NALs in the frame. I see two different behaviour - ffmpeg don't care about presence SPS and PPS NALs in frame. Wowza don't add SPS and PPS from avcC in case such NALs presented in the frame and no matter where at the begining or at the middle/end.